# depth value of openni_camera

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello. I am doing simulation using openni_camera(https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera) on Gazebo. I'd like to get the depth value of real type, but uint8[] will return as shown by document(http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html). Since 4 data was stored for one point, I converted it to float32 using union, but we could not get the correct value. What do these four data represent? Also, how can we obtain the depth value? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16896/depth-value-of-openni_camera/) by [Akitoshi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3482/akitoshi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

there are a few related questions and answers in ROS answers, e.g. http://answers.ros.org/question/160611/how-can-i-get-depth-data-from-kinect/

I'm not sure what you mean by 4 data stored per point, maybe RGBD? The depth image topic will give you D. After converting to float32, you get depth values so there'll be a total of width*height values.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akitoshi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3482/akitoshi/) on 2017-08-02**:
Thank @iche033! Thanks to the URL you sent, I was able to solve it! Perhaps one depth value was converted to four data, but I did not know how to reprocess the original data. However, I were able to obtain depth values by using openCV!